# Syntax Error on Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Hi, I'm getting a syntax error in the below script, on line #5. Can someone help me? I'm a novice in batch scripting.

```
echo off *****************************************************************
echo off *                                                               *
echo 0ff *   BATCH SCRIPT TO MOVE ING PH TO GP5000 (FULL PROCESS)        *
echo off *                                                               *
echo off *****************************************************************
for %%A in (%*) do if exist %%A copy %%A W:\IP5000_ING_2-up\Input Folder
W:
cd \IP5000_ING_2-up\Processed Docs on Success
choice /C X /T 120 /D X > nul
move /y *.* \IP5000_ING_2-up\ING_Tmp
cd \IP5000_ING_2-up\Processed Docs on Error
move /y *.* \IP5000_ING_2-up\ING_Tmp
cd \IP5000_ING_2-up\ING_Tmp
dir
move /y *.* \\10.0.238.197\Duplex\ING_Domtar_18inch
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo off` is a command on its own. To echo ouput, just use `echo`:

```
@echo off
echo *****************************************************************
echo *                                                               *
echo *   BATCH SCRIPT TO MOVE ING PH TO GP5000 (FULL PROCESS)        *
echo *                                                               *
echo *****************************************************************
```

Note that `@` means 'echo off for this line only'. That way you can prevent echoing the echo off command itself.

On line with the for loop, there seems to be a problem too. Your path has a space in it, so I think it should be quoted. Also, I'm not sure about `%*`. Did you mean just `*` or `*.*`?

```
for %%A in (*.*) do if exist "%%A" copy "%%A" "W:\IP5000_ING_2-up\Input Folder"
```

The same goes for other paths in your script.

Comment: Can I use * to grab whatever files are in the folder or if I use * will have the same effect?

Comment: I made the corrections and execute flawlessly with no errors, thank you very much for help.